# How to solve this Unknown Syntax error " near unexpected token `(' "?

Tags: shell, terminal, syntax, zsh

When run on a Mac terminal, I get the following error:

```
syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

This is the line raising the error:

```
set mpr = (cat $dat | grep "256 256 128" |grep ok | awk '{print  $8}') echo "found mprages, $mpr"
```

Any idea how to solve this syntax error? Thanks a lot!

The complete code would be:

```
set s = $1
SUBJECTS_DIR= <path>
export SUBJECTS_DIR
set log = $SUBJECTS_DIR/recon-all-commands.log
set dcmdir = <path>
set subjid = echo $s |gawk -F- '{print $2}'

if (-e $dcmdir/$s/scan.log) then

 . echo "found scan.log, finding mprages" set dat = $dcmdir/$s/scan.log

else

 . echo "no scan.log"

endif

set mpr = (cat $dat | grep "256 256 128" |grep ok | awk '{print  $8}') echo "found mprages, $mpr"

echo recon-all -i $dcmdir/$s/$mpr -all -s $subjid >> $log
```

Comment: Which shell are you using?

Comment: @choroba -zsh is the shell I am using

Comment: That looks like csh code. You're using the wrong interpreter to execute it.

Comment: This is definitely not zsh, though I don't know what it really is. No wonder that zsh complains about it. I suggest that you rewrite the program in the zsh programming language (or any other language you like).

Answer (score 0):

Shell version is not competable
Use the command `ls -al /bin/sh` to get the version

Solution:

```
 $ sudo dpkg-reconfigure dash
```

and then select no or "No", and confirm. Error Solved